# Necessary and sufficient condition for a topological space to be Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

**Problem:** Show that $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal $\Delta=\{x\times x|x\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times X$.

**Attempt:**
Suppose $X$ is Hausdorff. Then to show $\Delta$ is closed, we need
to show $y,\left(X\times X\right)\backslash\Delta$ is open. For $\forall\left(x,y\right)\in\left(X\times X\right)\backslash\Delta$,
we have $x\neq y$ by construction. By Hausdorffness, $\exists\mbox{ open sets }U_{x},V_{y}$
such that $x\in U_{x}$ and $y\in V_{y}$ and $U_{x}\cap V_{y}=\emptyset.$
Furthermore, $\left(x,y\right)\in U_{x}\times V_{y}$, which is open.
Since $x,y$ are arbitrary, we can then write $\left(X\times X\right)\backslash\Delta=\cup_{\left(x,y\right)}U_{x}\times V_{y}$
and the latter is open as it's an arbitrary union of open sets. Therefore,
$\Delta$ is closed.

To show the converse, we suppose $X$ is not Hausdorff. Then $\exists a,b$
such that $a\neq b$ and for any $U,V$ such that $a\in U$ and $b\in V$,
$\exists z\in U\cap V\neq\emptyset.$ Suppose $\Delta$ is closed
in $X\times X,$ then $\left(X\times X\right)\backslash\Delta$ is
open. We can then rewrite $\left(X\times X\right)\backslash\Delta=\cup_{\left(x,y\right)}U_{x}\times V_{y}$
where $U_{x}$ and $V_{y}$ are open in $X$. However, for $\left(a,b\right)$
we have $U_{a}\times V_{b}\cap\Delta\neq\emptyset$ by previous arguments.
Therefore, $\exists z\in\Delta$ such that $z\in\left(\cup_{\left(x,y\right)}U_{x}\times V_{y}\right)\backslash\left[\left(X\times X\right)\backslash\Delta\right]$.
Therefore, $\left(X\times X\right)\backslash\Delta\neq\cup_{\left(x,y\right)}U_{x}\times V_{y}$,
which is contradiction. Therefore, $\Delta$ is not closed.

Comment: Are you looking to have your proof verified?

Comment: This looks correct --- what exactly is the question?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes. I am hoping that kind people here can take a look at my proof and give me some suggestions. In return, I will contribute to this forum by looking at others'. Isn't it the spirit of this forum?

Comment: @AshwinIyengar I hope I can get my proof verified..

Comment: @DaqianSun I just wanted to be sure that is what you wanted. This looks good to me.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks! I wasn't very sure since I am new to topology. Still learning:)

Comment: Ah ok, yeah this looks right!

Comment: There is a type of space that  gets little attention, called an Urysohn space. A space $S$ is Urysohn iff whenever $p,q\in S$ with $p\ne q$, there are open sets $P,Q$ with $p\in P, q\in Q$ and $\bar P \cap \bar Q=\phi.$